# Jquery 'this' selector issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a problem:

When I click on my '.glass' div it opens multiple '.permalinks' divs, but I just want to open the one I click.

This is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
        $('.glass').click(function() {
            $('.permalinks').slideToggle(function() {
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is the CSS:

```
    .permalinks {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;top:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    }

    .reblog, .link, .like {
        display:inline-block;
        margin:2%;
        margin-top:45%;
        padding:7% 7% 4% 7%;
    }

    .reblog, .link, .like {
        width:10%;
    }

    .reblog {
        background:#317FD4;
    }

    .link {
        background:#38C264;
    }

    .like {
        background:#ED4A4A;
    }

    .glass {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background:#f3f3f3;
    }
```

And this the html:

```
      <div class="permalinks">

      <div class="reblog"><center><img src=""></center></div>

      <div class="link"><center><img src=""></center></div>

      <div class="like"><center><img src=""></center></div>

      </div>

      <img class="glass" src="" width="5%">
```

If you could tell me what I've done wrong, please.

Comment: Where is the `this` in this?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that corresponds to this jquery?

Comment: Is `.permalinks` a child of `.glass`? Might be helpful to see the HTML.

Comment: Is .permalinks a child of .glass?

Answer (score 1):

assign the click handler to `.permalinks` and use `$(this).slideToggle()`

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.permalinks').click(function() {
        $(this).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yRFSV/

Answer (score 0):

If `.permalinks` is a child of `.glass`, then it's easy:

```
    $(window).ready(function() {
        $('.glass').click(function() {
            $(this).find('.permalinks').slideToggle(function() {
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Ha, almost identically worded answers. Oh well.

Comment: @kunalbhat I answered 20secs+ faster than you (at the moment of this msg, mine has `1min ago` while yours `40 secs ago`) :D Good thing we think alike, let's give ourselves some +1 lol

Answer (score 0):

If `.permalinks` is a child of `.glass`, then you can select it directly upon click.

```
$('.glass').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.permalinks').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. `.permalinks` is after `.glass` in the DOM tree
   Use `$(this).next('.permalinks').slideToggle(function() {`
2. `.permalinks` is before `.glass` in the DOM tree
   Use `$(this).prev('.permalinks').slideToggle(function() {`

Comment: It's not working, I've edited my question with the css and html. Tell me what I've done wrong please.

Comment: @PaulBorsan, just updated my answer. According to your html looks like you need my option 2 (using `.prev()` to get the first previous sibling.)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.glass').click(function() {
        $(this).children('.permalinks').slideToggle(function() {
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with `.children()` is that it just transverses one dom level. Since we did not see OP's html, this might not work if `.permalinks` is nested on something else.